# Useful Force IDE Apex Code Templates

Tags: apex, ide, eclipse

I am not sure if this question gets closed but looking for shortcuts in Force IDE similar to what we have in Java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates

I am sure people who are working on salesforce for a long time would definitely have some templates.

Please share with us and it definitely helps people like me who are new and coming from Java background.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Force.com IDE, but I know MavensMate has a selection of templates. [MavensMate-Templates](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Templates)

Comment: @DanielBallinger , Thanks for the link. I used Mavensmate IDE for a week but the saving file to the server was very painful. At time it would take around 5 mins..I wish we had all these features in Force IDE.

Comment: @javanoob Most people see better performance with recent MavensMate than the Force.com IDE. And it looks like MavensMate has succeeded in attracting a community who contribute templates but the Force.com IDE [has not](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/master/com.salesforce.ide.ui.editors/templates/default-templates.xml). So I suggest you take another look at MavensMate.

Comment: @KeithC I have used both MavensMate and Eclipse Force.com IDE for a while, and I am still using both for daily work. Considering the speed of compilation and refreshing from server, MavensMate is no comparison to Force.com IDE. I would say the success of MavensMate is the success of Sublime, not itself.

Comment: @KeithC Are you not facing this problem https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/478 --Actually this led me to use ForceIDE

Comment: @javanoob Given that the problem sounds like it is in the underlying API that both tools use changing tools probably won't help. Yes from time to time I get very slow saves but have just grown to accept the problem.

Comment: n.b. I'm using latest Force.com eclipse IDE that exploits Tooling API and noticed that compile times became much much faster than earlier versions of the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @crop1645 both Force IDE and mavensmate use tooling API..Atleast I did not see any difference in save time between mm and Force IDE after turning on tooling api in mm.

Comment: @javanoob - yes, I knew that but many have said in the past that MM is faster than Eclipse when it comes to compiling - I'm not sure this is still true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that it will help developers how want create custom Apex templates in Eclipse IDE.

Currently the Salesforce Plugin for Apex Provides you with:

- ApexClass-Default
- ApexClass-Inbound_Email_Service
- ApexClass-Test_Class

You can add your custom template to the above list and it shows up, its simple:

1. Navigate to the Eclipse Installation Folder –> Configuration –>org.eclipse.osgi . Search for .template. You can see the files listed above.
2. Open any of the ApexClass*  file using your fav text editor.
3. Modify the file. Add custom comments , descriptions etc.
4. Save the file as ApexClass-.template.
5. Restart your Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment chain, I don't believe the Force.com IDE currently has Apex Code Templates.

I do know that MavensMate in sublime has templates when creating new components.  See [MavensMate-Templates](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Templates).

Comment: Looks like I had tooling api turned off in my mavensmate..now after turning on the save time is greatly improved also I see there are so many other cool features in mavensmate..I am loving it! and no more feel like coding in EditPlus :)

Answer (score 0):

- Go to File -> New -> Apex Class
- Select a project and Choose a class name and click Next>
- You'll see the following: "Templates are 'New Class' templates found in the Apex Editor Templates preference page."On the bottom of the pop-up window.
- Click on Apex Editor Templates
- The Templates preference window pops up and here you can create your new templates, modify existing one or delete them.

Enjoy!